# Responsive image and text next to it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hey i want to make some text in the left side and one picture in the right side it should be responsive

i thought it should look like this

```
CATEGORY

text text text    mid        |-----|

text text text    mid        |img|

text text text    mid        |-----|
```

and when it sizes to small pictures i would like it like this:

```
CATEGORY

text text text  ......|sameimage|

text text text  ..... |IMAGEimg|

text text text text text text
```

here is my code for now:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">

            <a> </a><a> </a>
            <h2>Category Name</h2>
            <br>text test some things just for testing his text is unnecesarry
            <br>This is random text dont worry his text is unnecesarry
            <br>This text is unnecesarry his text is unnecesarry
            <br>It really is unnecesarry just decoration his text is unnecesarry
            <br>for testing purposes of the website's design his text is unnecesarry

            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="templates.php"><h3>More Templates</h3></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">

            <img class="img-responsive" src="test.jpeg" id="image">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

the problem when I view it on mobiles the text is like

```
category
text

text  ........ |IMAGE|

text  ..........|--------|

text

text

text
```

Comment: I think you have two ways to do it:
- Place each 'text' and 'image' inside a col-xs-(whatever)
- Display as a table (checkout bootstrap`s table)